# Why doesn't Scalaz have an asIdentity method?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Scalaz has an `asMA` method, but no `asIdentity` method. The following produces a compilation error in Scala 2.9.1 as shown:

```
Some(0).max(None)

<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type (with underlying type object None)
 required: Ordering[?]
              Some(0).max(None)
                          ^
```

which can be fixed with an explicit cast:

```
(Some(0):Identity[Option[Int]]).max(None)
```

It seems to me that this would be more elegant, if `asIdentity` existed:

```
Some(0).asIdentity.max(None)
```

Comment: This would get more attention with a `scala` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that `Identity` has a `Pure` instance:

```
scala> some(0).pure[Identity] max None
res0: Option[Int] = Some(0)
```

Note that you need to use `some(0)` instead of `Some(0)` here so that you start with something of type `Option[Int]` instead of `Some[Int]`.

There's also `Identity.apply`:

```
scala> Identity(some(0)) max None
res1: Option[Int] = Some(0)
```

Given these options—and the fact that explicitly indicating that you want to wrap something in `Identity` is only necessary in a handful of cases like this, where you need to disambiguate—I'd guess the Scalaz designers just didn't see the need for an additional `asIdentity` method.